# Wordpress taxonomy last child separated by "en" instead of comma

Tags: php, wordpress, function, taxonomy

I'm trying to create a shortcode that outputs my custom taxonomies, separated by a comma, but i want the last comma to be "en" instead of a comma. So like this:

*taxonomy, taxonomy, taxonomy en taxonomy*

So far i have this:

```
// Assortiment shortcode

function verlichting_type( ){
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'verlichting_type' );
                foreach($terms as $term) {
                    $entry_terms .= $term->name . ', ';
                }
                $entry_terms = rtrim( $entry_terms, ', ' );
            return '<span class="verlichting__type"> ' . $entry_terms . ' </span>';
}
add_shortcode( 'verlichting_type', 'verlichting_type' );
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code? Are there any errors? What's the actual output? Please see [ask]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I dont have an example of the `$terms` or `$entry_terms` variable I had to make up some dummy data, but I think you should be able to extract my example and place it into your code.

I made use of the ternary operator (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to determine whether or not the final comma should be ',' or 'en':

```
<?php

function verlichting_type() {
    $entry_terms = "";

    $terms = [
        (object)['name' => 'taxonomy'],
        (object)['name' => 'taxonomy'],
        (object)['name' => 'taxonomy'],
        (object)['name' => 'taxonomy']
    ];
    
    echo '<span class="verlichting__type">';
    
    foreach ( $terms as $index => $term) {
        $enIndex = sizeof($terms) - 2;
        $end = (isset($terms[$enIndex]) && $index == $enIndex ? ' en ' : ', ');
        
        $entry_terms .= $term->name . $end;
    }
    
    $entry_terms = rtrim( $entry_terms, ', ' );
    
    return $entry_terms . '</span>';
}
```

This outputs:

```
<span class="verlichting__type">taxonomy, taxonomy, taxonomy en taxonomy</span>
```

This should work with any array length, e.g. if `$terms` only has 2 elements:

```
<span class="verlichting__type">taxonomy en taxonomy</span>
```

Or 1 element:

```
<span class="verlichting__type">taxonomy</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm! I updated your code a bit because there was an error with the css class. However, i see that after the last taxonomy name, there is a space which i need to get rid of. Any idea where to delete the extra space after the last taxonomy?

Comment: Would you be able to clarify a bit more as I cannot see a space after the last taxonomy, are you sure the space is not already present in the `$terms` variable?, You can see an example of my working code @ http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c87bf69cfa89b4b5c299ed3a0b3fdafcee4066ff

Comment: I'll dive firther into this. I can't seem to find out where the extra space after the end of the line comes from. Anyway, thanks for your help RJK!

Answer (score 2):

WordPress already have custom printf function with localize the output

So if your site language is Francais means

`wp_sprintf_l( '%l', ['Hello', 'world', 'never', 'give', 'up'] )`

The above code will output

`Hello, world, never, give, et up`

For Espanol:

`Hello, world, never, give y up`

As you noted based on the language the last comma will be added/removed